# HTTPS images not showing up for some users in HTML emails

Tags: html, outlook, exchange-server

There is a group of users who receive an HTML email that includes an image hosted by a third party.

Previously all users could see the image without issue. However the image host made a change on their end to use HTTPs instead of HTTP and now some users cannot see the images now. Users are using different versions of outlook but the issue appears to be on multiple versions. Also it was confirmed that outlooks is set to download images.

Also a user using outlook webmail could not see the image.

Is it possible that this is being blocked at an exchange server level?

I should clarify that the Email is updated and we do not have the ability to change the format of the URL.

Answer (score 0):

In the url for the image remove the http: or https: and just start the url with //yoursite.com

check below example

[image]

the code is `<img src="//cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/sprites.png?v=3c6263c3453b">`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately we are unable to edit the URL. I updated my post.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure.
In my template I use this linecode and works with http sentence

```
<a href= http://vbatools.pl ><img src=http://vbatools.pl/files/2013/11/VBATools_Logo.jpg style= border: none;  width= 32  height= 32  alt= VBATools /></a>
```

Anyway, I was build add-in to create new email message using HTMLcode from file or paste to text window: http://vbatools.pl/utworz-maila-z-kodu-html/
That what you should to worried about, that picture/file available from internet.
If you want to use internal file (from attachment) and hide it, [you should use](https://sendgrid.com/blog/embedding-images-emails-facts/) `"src=""cid:"`